# monacaのコンタクトプラグインを利用してコンタクト一覧を表示したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, cordova, angularjs

anguler+monacaのコンタクトプラグインを利用してコンタクト一覧を表示したいと考えています。

```js
      app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

　　　　document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        　var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        　options.filter = "";
        　options.multiple = true;
        　var fields = ["*"];
        　contact = navigator.contacts.find(
         　  fields   　   
              , function(success) { $scope.contact = success; }
        　　　, function(contactError) { aleat('contactError'); }
            　, options
          );
　　　　}, false);
      });
```

で、画面にcontactのidをとりあえず表示させたいのですが、

```html
    <ons-page ng-controller="MainController">
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row>

            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">{{contact[0].id}}</span>
               ・・・
```

一向に表示されません。何が悪いでしょうか……

Comment: 前回とタイトルが重複した質問になっています。もう少し具体的な質問をしたほうがいいかもしれません。console.log()などを利用してプログラムがどこまで走っているのか１つずつ処理を追ってみてください。

Answer (score 1):

jsをこんな感じに書き換えたらエラーは出なくなりました（`function(success){}`に入ることも確認できました）。
Onsen UIを使う場合はAngularJSとは記述がちょっと異なるようです（やり方次第なのかもしれませんが）。

```
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";
        options.multiple = true;
        var fields = ["*"];
        contact = navigator.contacts.find(
         　 fields   　   
            , function(success) { $scope.contact = success; }
        　　, function(contactError) { aleat('contactError'); }
            , options
        );
    }, false);
});
```

ただ、これだと`function(success) { $scope.contact = success; }`の部分で設定した値が保持できていないようですので、その辺は修正が必要になりそうです。